# How to read configuration text files in Java

Tags: java, configuration

I have made a textual minesweeper game ([here you can find the program](https://repl.it/@Dexter1997/Minesweeper)).
I want to initialize some data by the help of a file. The file should be readable for humans and easy to modify with a simple text editor.
The file should look for example like this and it should allow comments:

```
# columns and rows
size:10
# describes how the field is selected
# 1 - <o x x> (for example e 5 7 which means explore field with coordinates 5 7)
# 2 - easy entering format
format: 1 
# possibility that a field is bombed (1 / possibility)
possibility: 8
```

In which part of the program and in which manner should I read such a file? What is the most efficient way to read such a file? Thank you for all answers!

Comment: Could someone tell me why my question has got a downvote?

Comment: this question is very broad, and seems like a homework question.

Comment: perhaps it would behoove you to go to http://interpersonal.stackexchange.com and ask how to effectively express disagreement, and how to not take criticism of your question as a personal attack. Hope you have a good day, best of luck with your software engineering endeavors :)

Comment: Best answer in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16273174/how-to-read-a-configuration-file-in-java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Raw Java world uses Java propeties format to handle similar configuration tasks. Dedicated class [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) makes this trivial.

```
 try(Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Path.get("config.properties"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
     Properties properties = new Properties();
     properties.load(reader);
     int size = Integer.valueOf(properties.getProperty("size"));
     int format = Integer.valueOf(properties.getProperty("format"));
     .....
 }
```

Comment: I agree.  Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: If you dont like properties there is still yaml, json, xml ...  all of which wont re-invent wheels though some might need external libraries.

Comment: XML, YAML, JSON model tree structures, while OP requests a key-value storage, which is a simpler subset.

Answer (score 1):

if you use Java (and you do), work with Spring. it makes your life so much easier in such cases!

and specifically in this case, you just use something like

```
<context:property-placeholder 
    ignore-resource-not-found="true" 
    location="classpath:default.properties" />
```

and you have all the properties ready for use (it reads everything upon startup)

Comment: For the OP's needs, Spring is like using a cannon on a squirrel. Heavy to lift, hard to aim, and leaves a mess behind.